# Writing TestRunner classes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Working with a nodejs codebase coming from an extensive java background. I'm planning to really flesh out the unit tests in the service to help prevent all the devs from breaking each other's code.

However, my java background has taught me patterns like a TestRunner class within the unit test to help repetitive code/calls/UT setup and make the actual tests themselves quite small and readable.

Searching around this pattern seems nonexistent under mocha. Is this an anti-pattern? Is writing a TestRunner class within my UT file not worth in under nodejs?

To illustrate what I'm thinking (please excuse actual syntax, ect):

```
describe('classToTest', function() {
  it('should test the method', function() {
    var tmp = new ClassToTest_TestRunner().runWithVariable('123');
    assertTrue(tmp.run());
  });
});

class ClassToTest_TestRunner {
  var classToTest = new ClassToTest();
  runWithVariable(variable) {
    this.classToTest.method(variable)
  }
  run(){
    return ClassToTest.method();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. There are `before`/`beforeEach` hooks in Mocha, what else do you want to do that isn't covered by that?

Comment: I have certain configurations that need to be applied each time, but each configuration is slightly different and I don't like how it looks declaring the same ~10 loc with just slightly different strings or an undefined string.